# if not exists select into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure exports some data in a table. What i want to ensure is even if the table doesn't exists, it will be created. If it exists, I don't want the procedure to return `There is already an object named 'myFinalTable' in the database.` 
In order to check I'm doing this:

```
if not exists (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'dbo.myFinalTable')
begin
select * 
into dbo.myFinalTable
from #someTempIhaveDataIn
end
```

then I used

```
drop table dbo.myFinalTable
```

and ran it once. It worked, then I ran it again (the procedure) and it gave me the error mentioned above (there is already an object named..)

Comment: You'll probably find looking at the results of `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ` enlightening.

Comment: I think nothing wrong in this query, it should work. Try to fire same query in other window and make sure you have not created 'dbo.myFinalTable' before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not correct. Use this:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'myFinalTable'
           AND TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TableName]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN 
    select * into dbo.myFinalTable from #someTempIhaveDataIn
END
```